# YouTube Data API - how do I get the URL of the video I just uploaded?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-data-api

I can upload a video to my YouTube account using the YouTube Data API using the following sample code:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#update_a_video

2 queries:

a) How can I find the URL that users need to use in order to access the video after upload has completed?

b) I have seen old posts which state that only YouTube "Premium Partners" can set the monetization setting via one of the APIs.  However, when I look at the current YouTube membership types there are only: "All Creators", "Verified Channels" and "Partners" (https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/creator-benefits.html).  Is there a way to set the monetization setting and who can use this?

I have also seen that some people have tried to just use the YouTube account default monetization setting, but this did not appear to work ([How to enable monetization for videos uploaded with YouTube Data API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800665/how-to-enable-monetization-for-videos-uploaded-with-youtube-data-api-v3)).

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you can find the id of the new video in the Video instance object returned by the API,  and from there you can derive the URL. In the code look at these lines:

// Call the API and upload the video.
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

```
        // Print data about the newly inserted video from the API response.
        System.out.println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
        System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
```

Hope this helps.

massimo