# How can we figure out that the YouTube video is monetized using youtube/v3/videos?id=<> call?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Given a YouTube Video id, and using `youtube/v3/videos?id=<>` API call, how can we find that the video is monetized?  Which param in response signifies that?

e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1iqGiX0lSg`

Thanks,
Nimish

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to determine whether or not a video is monetized with a call to the YouTube Data API (which appears to be what you mean by `youtube/v3/videos?id`).

Instead, you'll need the [YouTube Content ID API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/).  Keep in mind that you'll have to be a partner of the CMS, and have the authentication of the CMS, to get visibility to a video's policy this way.  You'll probably want to determine a video's `policyId`, and then use the `policies.list` resource to determine the type of policy (I've never attempted this myself, though this is how I would start).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800665/how-to-enable-monetization-for-videos-uploaded-with-youtube-data-api-v3) for more info.