# Automatic monetization after video upload in c# (YouTube API)

Tags: c#, api, youtube, youtube-api

I can upload videos to youtube programatically, I have an adsense account. In my channel options "monetize in all countries" is selected. When I upload manually in youtube, advertisements start showing.

How can I make ads show automatically when I upload videos via API programatically. But I need C# code example which I couldn't find in youtube documentation page

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/upload_claim_sample

Answer (score 3):

If you are an Adsense account owner, you cannot monetize (claim) your videos via API. In order to monetize (claim) your videos, you should have CMS account..

I hope it helps,

Best,

Comment: Straight to the point @iwocan. Roman Sarvarov, found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33936556/6124253) here that I think might give you more insight on things.